# Attached properties on TreeViews

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attached-properties

So I have this code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Converters:GetElementTypeConverter x:Key="GetElementTypeConverter" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GetElementTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type Models:ServerItem}">
            <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command" Value="{Binding ConnectServer}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GetElementTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type Models:DatabaseItem}">
            <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command" Value="{Binding ConnectDb}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It defines some properties for tree view item, but it doesn't work entirely - I mean it sets foreground colors, but when I double click any item, it doesn't fire my command.

Comment: Well - I set one of the properties (the first one) on the treeview level and it runs ok, but the second one still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this is related to your previous question.

- With this setup you have that I mentioned yesterday, remember the `RelayCommand<T>` needs to be on the concerned element not the parent VM. That's why you're probably seeing the `Foreground` properties work fine but not the Command getting executed since the `DataContext` where the command is being looked for(`ServerItem` and `DatabaseItem`) does not actually define the Commands `ConnectServer` and `ConnectDb`.
- Also instead of having two triggers, set `ConnectDb` as default and use the trigger to set `ConnectServer` for just `ServerItem`'s on the concerned elements.

Now to fix your problem you can define `ConnectServer` command in your `ServerItem` and `ConnectDb` command in your `DatabaseItem`, or if you want to keep the commands in the DataContext of the `TreeView`, use a `RelativeSource` binding to find these commands from the `TreeView`.

something like (Tested this and it works fine):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ServerItems}">
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Style.Resources>
        <CommandBehaviors:GetElementTypeConverter x:Key="GetElementTypeConverter" />
      </Style.Resources>
      <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command"
              Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ConnectDb,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                              AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" />
      <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter"
              Value="{Binding Path=.}" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="Black" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.,
                                        Converter={StaticResource GetElementTypeConverter}}"
                      Value="{x:Type CommandBehaviors:ServerItem}">
          <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command"
                  Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ConnectServer,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                  AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground"
                  Value="Tomato" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**Update:** (Fix for the recursive `DoubleClick` event call of `TreeViewItem`'s)

In your class `MouseDoubleClick`

switch:

```
public class MouseDoubleClick {

  ...

  private static void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Control control = sender as Control;
    ICommand command = (ICommand)control.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    object commandParameter = control.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    command.Execute(commandParameter);
  }
}
```

to

```
public class MouseDoubleClick {

  ...

  private static void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Control control = sender as Control;
    var possibleTreeViewItem = sender as TreeViewItem;
    if (control == null || (possibleTreeViewItem != null && !possibleTreeViewItem.IsSelected))
      return;
    ICommand command = (ICommand)control.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    object commandParameter = control.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    command.Execute(commandParameter);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works almost ok - when I click top level child one command is run, but when I click second level child both commands are run.

Comment: @MarekMałek That's good, issue you mentioned just now has nothing to do with your code. it's default behavior in a `TreeView`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9132278/1834662 <- check this for an explanation "why". Also has a fix for the same.

Comment: @MarekMałek I've updated my answer with a fix for the recursive call at the bottom of the post :)